# Can I put AMD firepro d700 GPU into a Windows PC

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, windows, apple

I have a Mac Pro with two amd firepro d700 GPUs. Can I pull one of those GPUs out and stick it right into a Windows pc? Or did AMD make these GPUs specifically for Apple only?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These style machines (as pictured) are made with proprietary connections and components.   The problem you'd have, even if you found a way to adapt the connection to a standard PCI-E slot, is that the drivers for the non-reference circuit board that chip is on do not exist for Windows.

Considering that these are GPUs on part with a modern $200-250 card like the GTX 1050 or 1060, I'd save yourself the heartache of wrecking your tech and just get a new card for the PC.